# Does Google Play Developers Account provide user information?

Tags: android, google-play-services, account

I was trying to add a logic in my application so that I can stop or avoid my application from Piracy \ Copied
I don't own a google play developer's account and I am curious to know that is google provide any kind of information about user who had downloaded my application ? An email id of user maybe? 
Anything which can be used to authenticate any user ?
Apologies for the off-topic question.

Answer (score -1):

That's a good question !

I search a little and the answer is in the [Developer Distribution Agreement for Android](https://play.google.com/about/developer-distribution-agreement.html).
It's says in the 9th point that personal data, including store and devices utilisation data can be use (As well as others data, but no mentions of them...) respecting the [Google Privacy Policy](https://www.google.com/intl/en-GB/policies/privacy/).

> 9.1 In order to continually innovate and improve the Store, Google may collect >certain usage statistics from the Store and Devices, including but not limited >to, information on how the Store and Devices are being used.
>
> 9.2 The data collected is examined in the aggregate to improve the Store for >users and Developers and is maintained in accordance with Google's Privacy >Policy. To ensure the improvement of Products, limited aggregate data may be >available to you upon written request.

BUT e-mail informations and other sensible data like this must be wrote down. So don't worry